# Why it has duplicated insertion using sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

Here is my db table schema,

```
S_DB_Column _db_ott_option[N_DB_OTT_OPTION] = 
{   
    {"int",         "ott_param_type",               "%d"},  
    {"int",         "ott_param_id",                 "%d"},  
    {"int",         "ott_param_value",              "%d"},  
    {"char (128)",  "ott_param_name",               "%Q"},      
};
```

I want to control movie subtitle pid in db.
DB used auto increment.

example, my query are below,

```
insert or replace into _ottsubt ( ott_param_type, ott_param_id, ott_param_value, ott_param_name ) values ( 0, 9291, 8190, 'Movie 1' );

insert or replace into _ottsubt ( ott_param_type, ott_param_id, ott_param_value, ott_param_name ) values ( 0, 9291, 260, 'Movie 1' );
```

record is duplicated in the table,

I want to update if same record is existed and want to insert if same record is not existed.

Comment: I used same query at the other code "insert or replace into" but i am not sure why it happen different result. something mistake but I don't know what it is....

Comment: Edit your post to show how the table defined? That is there needs to a constraint (UNIQUE explicit or implied for the replace to be enacted). By the looks of of you either need to specify UNIQUE on the **id** column or have **id** column as PRIMARY KEY (implied UNIQUE).

Comment: create table _ottsubt(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ott_param_type int, ott_param_id int, ott_param_value int, ott_param_name char (128))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that none of the columns being inserted have a UNIQUE constraint.

I believe that you want to use the following to create the table :-

```
create table if not exists _ottsubt(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ott_param_type int, ott_param_id int UNIQUE, ott_param_value int, ott_param_name char (128));
```

Then the above will work.

### Working Example :-

```
drop table if exists _ottsubt;
create table if not exists _ottsubt(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ott_param_type int, ott_param_id int UNIQUE, ott_param_value int, ott_param_name char (128));
insert or replace into _ottsubt ( ott_param_type, ott_param_id, ott_param_value, ott_param_name ) values ( 0, 9291, 8190, 'Movie 1' );
insert or replace into _ottsubt ( ott_param_type, ott_param_id, ott_param_value, ott_param_name ) values ( 0, 9291, 260, 'Movie 1' );
SELECT * FROM _ottsubt;
```

### Result :-

[image]

---

Alternatively you could drop the **id** column and instead make the **ott_parm_id** col the PRIMARY KEY using (and an alias of the **rowid**) :-

```
create table if not exists _ottsubt(ott_param_type int, ott_param_id int INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ott_param_value int, ott_param_name char (128));
```

- Note AUTOINCREMENT has been dropped, it's probably not required and it's inefficient as per [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html), which includes :-

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
>   disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
>   usually not needed.